# VBA script to consolidate multiple excel sheets into one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Im looking for a VBA script to consolidate multiple Excel sheets into one sheet in a different folder location with the name "consolidated.xlsx". 
I feel this is a rather simple VBA script but I tried creating a few from.the web and it didnt work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

EDIT: I have this code that does consolidation, but its a bit complicated. How can I integrate this into your code "Consolidation part". I already wrote the code for opening the Target workbook but not sure how the loop will work to read All the available data and consolidate them into my target sheet (leaving any blank fields). Maybe the code below will help:

```
Sub test()

Dim m1, Filenamev, Filenamev2 As String
Dim loopvar, i As Integer

m1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("c2")
mm1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("b2")
loopvar = Sheet2.Cells(1, 5)

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Clear

Workbooks.Open Filename:=m1, ReadOnly:=True
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("MultiSheetPaste.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
False, Transpose:=False
'Windows("DAta1.xlsx").Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(mm1).Close

i = 1

Do While i <= loopvar - 1

Filenamev = Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, 3)
Filenamev2 = Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, 2)
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Filenamev, ReadOnly:=True
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("MultiSheetPaste.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Dim m As String
m = ActiveCell.Row
'MsgBox "m"

Range("a" & m + 1).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
'Windows("DAta2.xlsx").Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(Filenamev2).Close
i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the code you've tried, and explain why it didn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jumping off point. The code below will prompt a user to select a file(s) [you can see that multi-select is enabled], then iterate over that selection. I think you'll be able to fill-in the blanks from there:

```
Option Explicit
Sub OpeningFiles()

Dim SelectedFiles As FileDialog
Dim NumFiles As Long, FileIndex As Long
Dim TargetBook As Workbook

'prompt user to select a file or multiple files
Set SelectedFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With SelectedFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Pick the files you'd like to consolidate:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

'check to see if user clicked cancel
If SelectedFiles.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

'start the loop over each file
NumFiles = SelectedFiles.SelectedItems.Count
For FileIndex = 1 To NumFiles
    'set a reference to the target workbook
    Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Open(SelectedFiles.SelectedItems(FileIndex))
    'do your consolidating here
    '...
    TargetBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next FileIndex

MsgBox ("Consolidation complete!")

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey again Dan. Thanks for the help :) I want the macro to select a specific set of files (these are constant) and just consolidate them into a single file called "consolidated.xlsx" in a different folder. Can u help?

Comment: Basically I can add the file names in another worksheet and the macro would consolidate those files without asking me to select them manually.

Comment: I understand and think something like that is possible -- rather than iterating over the `SelectedFiles` object, you need to iterate over an array of filepaths to known workbooks. Right?

Comment: Yup, thats correct. I found a file online that does that but seems that the code is locked "I cant step into" the macro. I'll share it shortly. Its okay but I need to change a few things in the code but unable to

Comment: Hi Dan, Please check my code above and let me know if it is possible to incorporate the consolidation part into your code. Thanks

Comment: Had More than 40 sheets to combine , used this above macro code and it worked very smooth without any issues. +1 Kudos.

Comment: Thanks @BetaCoder -- that's a handy snippet to keep in your pocket. While not quite a "cornerstone" (like finding the last row) of Excel VBA, looping through user-selected files is something my scripts need to do on the regular